# Emacs: send output of eval to a new buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to eval a buffer and send the result to a new buffer. How do I "send" the result of the eval-buffer function to the content of a new buffer? here my attempt:

```
(set-buffer (get-buffer-create "test"))  ; create new buffer

(let ((value (eval-buffer)) .... ; how to put this inside the new buffer?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This evaluates the contents of buffer `evaluate-me` and prints the value of each toplevel form to the buffer `output`:

```
(eval-buffer "evaluate-me" (get-buffer-create "output"))
```

Do <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>f</kbd> `eval-buffer` to see the documentation that explains why this works. The second argument to `eval-buffer` is named `PRINTFLAG`, of which the docstring says:

```
PRINTFLAG controls printing of output:
 A value of nil means discard it; anything else is stream for print.
```

The slightly confusing thing about this is Emacs's unusual concept of what counts as an "output stream". Buffers, markers (locations in buffers), and the echo area can all be treated as "streams", as can any function that takes a character argument. Look up the docstrings of the `print` function or `standard-output` variable for more info.

The more general way to make things happen inside another buffer is the macro `with-current-buffer`. Unlike `set-buffer`, it takes care of restoring the original context cleanly even if errors happen in the wrapped code.

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "output")
  (insert "some text"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `value` calculation appears wrong: since `set-buffer` will switch to the new buffer, `eval-buffer` will evaluate the contents of the new empty buffer. My understanding is that you want to evaluate the contents of the previous buffer and print its value in the new buffer:

```
(let ((value (eval-buffer)))
  (set-buffer (get-buffer-create "test"))
  (print value))
```

If you want the new buffer to be visible to the user, replace `set-buffer` with `switch-to-buffer`.